# Office 365 Add-In - How do I hide the task pane?

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-apps, office-js

Currently, my task pane is shown using the Ribbon ShowTaskPane command.

```
 <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
```

How do I hide the task pane in Javascript?

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At present, the Office add-in doesn't support to hide the task pane via Office JavaScript API.

You may submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you require this feature.

Comment: Still not supported?

Comment: Any update on this? I am also looking for a solution which closes the task pane once the task has been done.